# Word for "One who is proctored"

Tags: single-word-requests

My university has a policy of assigning a proctor to each student for the duration of their study.
The proctor is supposed to be something akin to a mentor/guide.
I am looking for a word that describes my relationship to them. i.e. something like proctee? However, Merriam Webster did not appear to have a word like it.

My intended use is something like

> Respected Sir,
> I am [so and so], a fresher at [so and so].
> I am one of your [insert plural form of word for "one who is proctored"].
> (and so on and so forth)

Compound words and phrases should be perfectly fine.

Comment: What country is this? Terminology for universities varies a lot (I've not heard of students having proctors in UK or US). No reason you couldn't say "You are my proctor" (or if you want to be more tentative as a form of politeness you could say something like "I understand that you are my proctor").

Comment: I agree with Stuart F: the reason you are having to invent a word  is that the sentence needs rearranging. (I would add that, in the West, nobody writes or says "respected Sir".)

Comment: *Proctee* would make about as much sense as *mentee* (for one to whom another serves as *mentor),* which does have currency despite my best efforts to promote *telemachus* in its stead. But of course, the tribunal of use does not base its rulings on what makes sense.

Comment: @Greybeard: Nobody? Such hyperbolic generalizations commonly (and insultingly) imply that flesh-and-blood exceptions are nobodies. And even if such a salutation should strike the recipient as out of the common, I very much doubt it would cause offense or irritation. (Also, why assume that the social context is or is in "the West"?)

Comment: To @StuartF’s point.  Can you point to a dictionary defintion that covers this usage of *proctor*?

Comment: @BrianDonovan *that flesh-and-blood exceptions are nobodies* Your English must differ from mine. *I very much doubt it would cause offense or irritation.* - Did I mention either of those? It might cause amusement and detract from the letter's contents -- Have a look at the question again - you may have missed some contextual clues.

Comment: @Jim, the term apparently functions as a technical term, and has an explicitly stipulated meaning, at the OP's institution. Everybody working within that institutional setting is bound by that stipulation, regardless of whether the term is used that way anywhere else, and regardless of whether such use is recognised by general-purpose dictionaries.

Comment: @jsw29 - Understood.  It’s just too bad that when exposed to the wider English-speaking community that usage will receive puzzled expressions.  One might think that an institution might be more inclined to impart useful knowledge to its students.

Comment: @jsw29 I'm guessing that invigilants call their invigilators "proctors" for courses on proctology. :)

Comment: My university assigns profs as proctors, who are supposed to be a guide of sorts.

Comment: > What country is this?
India.

Comment: > The reason you are having to invent a word is that the sentence needs rearranging:
I ended up using "You are my proctor".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can say- supervisee(s)
since your usage seems to be in a formal environment.

However, you can also use proctee(s). It isn't actually a word, but is suitable for informal environments.

Comment: Sorry, Amrita. Non-words are not suitable as answers on ELU, as has been discussed in the past. The 'U' stands for 'usage'. // And with 'Respected Sir', OP defines a hghly formal context.